# JSONArray won't read double from SeekBar

Tags: java, android, arrays, double, seekbar

I am quite new to Android and have a problem reading multiple SeekBar double values to the JSONArray. The code I have works for ints (I have other parts that work that way), but I somehow can't make it work with a double value.

I have been searching for answers, but couldn't quite find what I was looking for and fix it.

The data needs to be read from the MainActivity file to the Conclusion class.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void conclusion(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Conclusion.class);

    intent.putExtra("s", (seekBar.getProgress() / 4));
    intent.putExtra("s2", (seekBar2.getProgress() / 4));
    intent.putExtra("s3", (seekBar3.getProgress() / 4));
    intent.putExtra("s4", (seekBar4.getProgress() / 4 ));
    intent.putExtra("s5", (seekBar5.getProgress() / 4 ));
    intent.putExtra("s6", (seekBar6.getProgress() / 4 ));
    intent.putExtra("s7", (seekBar7.getProgress() / 4 ));
    intent.putExtra("s8", (seekBar8.getProgress() / 4 ));
    intent.putExtra("s9", (seekBar9.getProgress() / 4 ));

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Conclusion.java**

```
    double seekBar = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("s", 0);
    double seekBar2 = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("s2", 0);
    double seekBar3 = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("s3", 0);
    double seekBar4 = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("s4", 0);
    double seekBar5 = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("s5", 0);
    double seekBar6 = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("s6", 0);
    double seekBar7 = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("s7", 0);
    double seekBar8 = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("s8", 0);
    double seekBar9 = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("s9", 0);
```

**and JSONArray in the Conclusion.java** both are in the onCreate() method

```
    JSONArray jscales= new JSONArray();
    jscales.put(seekBar);
    jscales.put(seekBar2);
    jscales.put(seekBar3);
    jscales.put(seekBar4);
    jscales.put(seekBar5);
    jscales.put(seekBar6);
    jscales.put(seekBar7);
    jscales.put(seekBar8);
    jscales.put(seekBar9);
```

I have tried moving the calculation to different parts, but to no avail. I know the JSONArray should be able to read a double, so that can't be the problem.

How can I read this double value into the JSONArray?

Comment: What results are you getting

Comment: It doesn't give any results if I try it like this. It only says if I hover over the jscales.put(seekBar) that I have an Unhandled Exception: JSONException. If I use all ints, it does work but it needs to be a double.

Comment: Problem is, if I try to catch the error it doesn't show anything either. It just gives the value of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast your result you are passing to the Intent.putExtra() method to a double data type or use Intent.putDouble() instead.  Like this:

```
     intent.putExtra("s", ((double)seekBar.getProgress() /
```

4)); because you are trying to get a double whilst you put in an int

Comment: Thank you so much! That was indeed the problem, it now works. 
I tried to upvote your answer as well, but it says after I earn a total of 15 reputation it will change the publicly displayed post score.